# Iterate through a list on button press in flutter using dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, listview, dart

Hello i need to display one item in the list.want to iterate through the list one by one, each time the button is pressed?. but am failing to find a way. Here is my my list

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "quidem molestiae enim",
"date": "2021, Jun, 20-24"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa",
"date": "2019, Feb, 20-24"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "omnis laborum odio",
"date": "2021, Jan, 20-26"
},`enter code here`
]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate through the list one by one, each time the button is pressed?

Comment: yes please i need help on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your own list, I've created a sample list called `weekdays`. Please replace that list with your `weeksModel` list.

What I've done is a basic list iteration in flutter, nothing much. Since I do not have your `WeeksModel` model or the `e` json, I don't think I could help any further.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WeekWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeekWidgetState createState() => _WeekWidgetState();
}

class _WeekWidgetState extends State<WeekWidget> {
  List weekdays = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
  ];

  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(weekdays[index]),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (index < weekdays.length - 1) {
              setState(() {
                index++;
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text("Next item"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: i have a demo one here pleasehttps://6074dd06066e7e0017e7a659.mockapi.io/api/weeksdata/weeksDate

Comment: You should have included this in your original question..

Comment: am failing to get the index on each item..

Comment: Are you good up to the point of generating the `weeksModel` list by getting the response? Still no idea of the `WeeksModel` model.

Comment: my response is a future<dynamic>

Comment: Hello thanks for this Answer was able to to figure it out.. Using your Answer  Helped me a lot to point me in the right Direction : here i had to await my Future list which is returned in order to Iterate through it as you Suggested. void loadweekdata()async{

  List weekdays = await API.getDates();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value)  {

    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      weekday = weekdays;
    });
  });
  setState(() {
    // weekday = weekday;
  });

}